# Python: merging 2 dictionaries (from csv file) with same key AND values

Tags: python, csv

I have these two DictReader-ed csv files:

```
A = {"Name": "Alex", "Age": 17} {"Name": "Bob", "Age": 20"} {"Name": "Clark", "Age": 24"}
B = {"Age": 17, "Class": "Economy"} {"Age": 24, "Class": "IT"} {"Age":17, "Class": Arts}
```

and several more bracketed values.

Is it possible to join them to form this:

```
{"Name": "Alex", "Age": 17, "Class": [{"Economy"}, {"Arts"}]}
{"Name": "Clark", "Age": 24, "Class": [{"IT"}]}
```

In short, joining them when they have the same `Age` and put all the same classes into a   list?

So far I've only read both dicts:

```
import csv

A=open('A.csv')
A_reader = csv.DictReader(A)
B=open('B.csv')
B_reader = csv.DictReader(B)

for item in A_reader:
   print(item)

for item in B_reader:
   print(item)
```

but unsure of how to merge them as mentioned.

Thank you!

EDIT: The csv given is so that no two people will have the same age.

Comment: what if two people have same age ?

Comment: It is impossible to have structure like: "Class": [{"Economy"}, {"Arts"}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
A = [{"Name": "Alex", "Age": 17}, {"Name": "Bob", "Age": 20}, {"Name": "Clark", "Age": 24}]
B = [{"Age": 17, "Class": "Economy"}, {"Age": 24, "Class": "IT"}, {"Age":17, "Class": "Arts"}]

C = []
for a in A:
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c["Class"] = []
    for b in B:
        if a["Age"]==b["Age"]:
            c["Class"].append(b["Class"])
    C.append(c)
```

Result is:

```
[{'Name': 'Alex', 'Age': 17, 'Class': ['Economy', 'Arts']},
 {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20, 'Class': []},
 {'Name': 'Clark', 'Age': 24, 'Class': ['IT']}]
```

If it doesn't work for you, let me know :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, is there a way such that, I don't have to import any modules other than csv or pandas?

Comment: yes, you can directly modify A list.

Comment: In fact, you can directly copy via `a.copy()`, no need to `import copy`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first turn `B` into a dictionary `{age: [classes]}`, then loop over `A` and combine the dictionaries – the more data you have, the more efficient it will be compared to looping over `B` over and over again. I'd use a `collections.defaultdict` for that.<sup>1</sup>

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# {17: ['Economy', 'Arts'], 24: ['IT']}
classes_by_age = defaultdict(list)

for b in B:
    classes_by_age[b['Age']].append(b['Class'])
```

With that in place, all you need to do is merge the dictionaries. I guess one of the most concise ways to do that is by passing a combination of the double asterisk operator `**` and a keyword argument to the `dict` constructor:

```py
merged = [dict(**a, Classes=classes_by_age[a['Age']]) for a in A]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you don't want to import `defaultdict`, you can simply initialize `classes_by_age` as an empty dictionary and in the loop do:

```py
for b in B:
    age = b['Age']
    class_ = b['Class']

    if age in classes_by_age:
        classes_by_age[age].append(class_)
    else:
        classes_by_age[age] = [class_]
```

But then you'd also have do adopt the final list comprehension to the one below, otherwise empty `Classes` would cause trouble:

```py
[dict(**a, Classes=classes_by_age.get(a['Age'], [])) for a in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Pandas in a comment. If that is an option, then you could try:

```
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.read_csv("A.csv")
df_B = pd.read_csv("B.csv")
result = df_A.merge(
    df_B.groupby("Age")["Class"].agg(list), on="Age", how="left"
).to_dict("records")
```